# How can I apply た form to -すぎ for conditional clause?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I want to say the following:

> "Please excuse if there was too little context."

I am wondering about two things now.

First, whether `-すぎ` is a suitable means to express **"too little**".

By now, I only encountered cases where it marked that something was *too much*, not *too little*.

Second, it seems to turn a word into a verb.

> 夕べお酒を飲みすぎました。

But I have no idea what class it enters into. That said, I also don't know how to properly bring it into **non-polite past/た-form** to use it in a conditional clause with (た)ら.

I have to add that I only know the "three textbook" verb classes right now.

I heard that Japanese grammar uses more classes usually, but for foreign language learners it's often simplified into three.

So I know class one, where い based ます stems turn into んだ、った and so on.

Then class two like たべる and finally the third class made up only of する and くる which inflect very irregularly ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can just do that by using small 少なすぎた (was too little)
2. Yes, it does turn the adjective into verb form as you note and you can then use the (た)ら (少なすぎたら）